# How to boot Ubuntu 14.04 CD on Toshiba m45-s165

Tags: boot, toshiba-satellite

I formatted my Toshiba m45-s165. Burned Ubuntu 14.04 several times to DVD. It won't boot the DVD. It boots format tool. It boots Toshiba recovery disk (win xp). It also boots win 7 repair DVD. I also tried to boot Mint disk and that won't work. Is it a Toshiba/Linux issue?

Comment: Did you really boot from DVD? Try tapping F12 or F2 keys when you power on your laptop.

Comment: Or the Delete key.

Comment: -1; what a mess, could you please be more specific?

Comment: What needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot from USB / Removable Media in the BIOS? Some older machines can't...

If you can, use UnetBootin to write the ISO to USB and try to boot from that. Also, try another flavor, such as [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org).

Comment: I can boot from DVD I set up to boot from DVD in bios.

Comment: Can I use portable hard drive when booting from USB or does it have to be thumb? Usb is in the boot menu.

Comment: Could be either, I personally prefer USB, it's a bit quicker.

Comment: Is Toshiba bios not compatable with Ubuntu?

Comment: No go with USB boot. Please help get DVD to boot.

Comment: @User293336 See bain's answer, no it isn't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The Toshiba M45-S165 BIOS is not compatible with the syslinux boot loader used on Ubuntu images, and the BIOS does not support booting from USB. What you can do is [download Plop boot manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html), burn plpbt.iso to a CD and boot it, then insert your Ubuntu  USB drive and select the USB option at the menu.

You may find that this laptop is problematic in other ways and requires some kernel parameters to work correctly eg. [noapic nolapic vga=771](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/dual-boot-linux-and-windows/). Ubuntu with the Unity desktop might also be a bit ambitious, perhaps Lubuntu or Xubuntu would perform better.

Comment: Is there an way to change the bios

Comment: [Toshiba support page](http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1042107). There is a DVD firmware upgrade and BIOS firmware upgrade which may help.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I installed vista from DVD. I am gonna try bios upgrade and possibly other OS.

Comment: Did you ever try booting the Plop iso?

Comment: No plop yet. Gonna try that also.